# Core java - class and object

Tags: java, class, oop, object

```
class Tyre {

    public Tyre() {
        super();
        System.out.println("constructor invoked for tyre");
    }
    public void front(long a)   {
        System.out.println("Tyre - long front");
    }
    public void back(int a)     {
        System.out.println("Tyre - int back");
    }
}

class NewTyre extends Tyre {

    public NewTyre() {
        super();
        System.out.println("constructor invoked for New tyre");
    }
    public void front(int a) {
        System.out.println("New Tire - int front");
    }
    public void back(long a) {
        System.out.println("New Tire - long back");
    }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 10;
        long b = 10;

        Tyre t = new NewTyre();
        t.front(a);
}
```

during compilation, method front(int) will be searched in class Tyre, Though Class Tyre is not having method front(int) but it has method front(long), as we know that long can accommodate int so this statement compiled successfully.

But during the runtime, the object created on heap belong to NewTyre, so here as per understanding output should be "New Tire - int front" but i am getting the output as "Tyre - long front"
Could someone please explain where iam getting wrong.

Comment: Only methods that the parent class defined can be "found" during runtime and as you stated `void front(int)` is not the same as `void front(long)` so `void front(int)` is not actually overloading anything. See also [`member hiding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: My bad, Thanks  BeyelerStudios, i got it..